# How to set Images in Center while even images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a 3d image carousel. But it works fine while there odd images. But when i add an image and then in even images position get change, it's don't come from center, it goes to left position.

**Here is jsfiddle link:**
https://jsfiddle.net/nriddhi/bp45zkun/

**Js code:**

```
jQuerynum = jQuery('.my-image-3d').length;
jQueryeven = jQuerynum / 2;
jQueryodd = (jQuerynum + 1) / 2;

if (jQuerynum % 2 == 0) {
  jQuery('.my-image-3d:nth-child(' + jQueryeven + ')').addClass('active');
  jQuery('.my-image-3d:nth-child(' + jQueryeven + ')').prev().addClass('prev');
  jQuery('.my-image-3d:nth-child(' + jQueryeven + ')').next().addClass('next');
} else {
  jQuery('.my-image-3d:nth-child(' + jQueryodd + ')').addClass('active');
  jQuery('.my-image-3d:nth-child(' + jQueryodd + ')').prev().addClass('prev');
  jQuery('.my-image-3d:nth-child(' + jQueryodd + ')').next().addClass('next');
}

jQuery('.my-image-3d').click(function() {
  jQueryslide = jQuery('.active').width();
  console.log(jQuery('.active').position().left);

  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('next')) {
    jQuery('.image-3d-carousel').stop(false, true).animate({left: '-=' + jQueryslide});
  } else if (jQuery(this).hasClass('prev')) {
    jQuery('.image-3d-carousel').stop(false, true).animate({left: '+=' + jQueryslide});
  }

  jQuery(this).removeClass('prev next');
  jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass('prev active next');

  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
  jQuery(this).prev().addClass('prev');
  jQuery(this).next().addClass('next');
});


// Keyboard nav
jQuery('html body').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
    jQuery('.active').prev().trigger('click');
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    jQuery('.active').next().trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Is there any solution? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You have four items last item is not visible. The total length of the items is larger then the document width.

[image]

This will solve your problem

[image]

Comment: it is working, but active item goes out of area, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

issue is not with the display property of the images. Issue is with "display flex" and "justify-content center" of ".image-3d-carousel". If we have odd number of images middle image will be centered as it is default "justify-content center" behavior. Of course if we have even number of images flex container tries to make its content centered, it means that middle images will be away from the center with the same distance.

From my point of view it'll be better to make some kind of frame, which will have width of active image and will be centered permanently. The frame contains carousel, which overflows it but with visible content.

You can see an example here https://jsfiddle.net/14u6Lmn3/

Centered frame container (just for meeting jsfiddle posting requirements):

```
.image-3d-frame {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 375px;
}
```

I've just wrapped carousel with container called "frame", removed property "justify-content center" as we center our main image with the frame and given initial offset as we have the second image active. Hope my idea is clear enough.

Comment: thanks for your effort, now it works only for even items, but again occurs problem with odd number, it goes to right position.